# ASP.NET back to the future: fix for time-travelling WebResource.axd / ScriptResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, .net, embedded-resource

I have stumbled upon embedded resources (`.js` files) not loading correctly in an `ASP.NET` application.

The issue was triggered by ASP.NET`'s way of handling calls to`WebResource.axd` when it tries to load assemblies built 'in the future' (e.g. built solution in Europe and quickly deployed it to US).

[Here are](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/07-07-05/scriptresource-axd-and-and-assemblies-built-in-the-future.aspx). [some articles](http://forums.asp.net/t/1711550.aspx?WebResource%20axd%20returns%20404%20and%20then%20starts%20working%20after%20a%20while%20on%20it%20s%20own). [detailing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178781/webresource-axd-works-on-one-computer-gives-404-on-another). [the](http://jamesnearn.blogspot.be/2011/08/webresourceaxd-returns-404-and-then.html). [issue](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/07/webresourceaxd-or-scriptresourceaxd.html).

**My question is:**

*Is there a way to convince the ASP.NET runtime to handle this case correctly?*

In the articles I have read on this issue, the recommendation is to `touch` the `dll`s "from the future", usually using the command (details on 'why' the strange syntax [courtesy Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/07/10/10432879.aspx)):

```
copy /B from_the_future.dll+,,
```

...but I'd rather not have to touch the deployed dlls (we ship the solution to various clients who install it themselves).

Can this be done just by tweaking `ASP.NET`? Is there a KB for it? (I couldn't find one)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. It's <s>42</s> *4.5.1*.

**Short story**: it's fixed in .NET 4.5.1 (October 2013) and up (see [.NET versions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions))

Upgrade the .NET framework if the project allows it.

**Long story**:

The problem stems from the code in class `System.Web.HttpCachePolicy`, in method `SetLastModified(DateTime date)`.

The [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setlastmodified%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this method says that an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown if..

> " *date* is later than the current DateTime."

This is what the code looks like:

```
public void SetLastModified(DateTime date)
{
  this.UtcSetLastModified(DateTimeUtil.ConvertToUniversalTime(date));
}
```

In .NET pre-4.5.1, the method `UtcSetLastModified()` looks like this (consistent with the MSDN description):

```
private void UtcSetLastModified(DateTime utcDate)
{
  utcDate = new DateTime(utcDate.Ticks - utcDate.Ticks % 10000000L);

  if (utcDate > DateTime.UtcNow)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("utcDate");  // exception here

  [...]
}
```

In .NET 4.5.1 and up, the method is changed - no more exception. This is NOT consistent with the MSDN description, but fixes the initial problem.

Related to the 'assembly from the future' issue, this means that if the assembly is from the future, it is treated like it is from the present.

```
void UtcSetLastModified(DateTime utcDate) {

   /*
    * DevDiv# 545481
    * Time may differ if the system time changes in the middle of the request. 
    * Adjust the timestamp to Now if necessary.
    */

    DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (utcDate > utcNow) {
        utcDate = utcNow;
    }
    [...]
}
```

I have verified that on .NET 4.5 RTM and updates (Jan 2013 and May 2013 (x64 client and x64 server - didn't have an x86 machine available) ), an exception is thrown.

I have also verified that it works on 4.5.1 (oct 2013 and feb 2014) and 4.5.2 (may 2014 - currently the latest release of .NET, not counting patches)

You can also [check the (latest?) code online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs#89b99749401f8c72#references), thanks to the new Roslyn-powered [.NET reference source code browser](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).